# How to customize the "make" action of Run configurations in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

I do not want to run the external maven task - since Intellij and Maven unfortunately do not synchronize/share the same output folders (which is an unresolved bug).  So I need to customize the "make" step.

The specific customization would be to add "clean" to it. The reason being the particular project does not work properly unless a clean were performed.

In addition I would like to add selection of multiple profiles to the "make".  BTW where is it possible to at least *view* the make command being executed?

Here is the gist of what  I am lookig for:

> mvn -Pprofile1 -Pprofile2 -D{some java opts} clean package

Comment: Change `Make` option it's not possible, `Add/Delete` only. I add `Run Maven Goal` as `clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true` and select necessary profiles and it's work perfect.

Comment: @DozortsevAnton  OK - that is a helpful answer. It may not be the answer I were hoping for - but you are not the developer on IJ ;)  So if you want some points pls make this an answer and I will award.

Comment: I glad that my comment was helpful for you. Develop with pleasure.

Comment: I have no problems making intellij and maven share the same build directory. It happens automatically when I import a standard maven project.

Comment: What is the -D doing in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently changing make is not possible.  I had offered to accept an answer from @Dozortsev Anton but he has not created an answer. Here is the content he provided:

> Change Make option it's not possible, Add/Delete only. I add Run Maven
>   Goal as clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true and select necessary
>   profiles and it's work perfect. –